# Unable to configure KVM (Qemu or Libvirt) on openSUSE Leap 42.1?

Tags: virtualization, opensuse, qemu, linux-kvm, virt-manager

I simply want to run multiple VM (not at the same time). I want them to be stored in another partition (mounted here `/run/media/shark/VM`) and not in the default storage pool `/var/lib/libvirt/images/default`.

No matter for me to use virsh or qemu-kvm, virtlib or qemu, CLI or GUI, I just want my VMs to run :)

I installed KVM as follows :

1. Start YaST and choose Virtualization > Installing Hypervisor and Tools.
2. Select KVM and confirm with Accept.
3. Confirm the list of packages that is to be installed with Install.
4. Agree to set up a network bridge by clicking Yes.

## KVM trying

I tried different ways :

### with virtlib (vm-install)

I tried :

```
 % vm-install --name "mageia5" \ 
--vcpus 2 --memory 1024 --max-memory 2048 \
--disk /run/media/shark/VM/VirtualMachines/mageia_raw_test,0,disk,w,8000,sparse=1 \
--disk /home/shark/Téléchargements/mageia_boot-nonfree.iso,1,cdrom \
--nic model=virtio \
--graphics cirrus --config-dir "/etc/libvirt/qemu"
```

Prompt for OS :

```
4: Other operating system
```

Then :

```
PXE Boot
(Y / N) [N] > N
Description > 

Virtual Disks:
  7.8 GB Hard Disk (file:/run/media/shark/VM/VirtualMachines/mageia_raw_test)
  0.1 GB CD-ROM or DVD (file:/home/shark/Téléchargements/mageia_boot-nonfree.iso)
Do you want to add another virtual disk?
(Y / N) [N] > N 

Network Adapters
  QEMU Virtualized NIC Card; Randomly generated MAC address
Do you want to add another virtual network adapter?
(Y / N) [N] > N

Specify the bootable virtual disk (often labeled as Disk 1) or the network
installation source URL.  Each CD, DVD, or ISO image required for installation
must be added as a virtual disk.
  1: Virtual Disk (0.1 GB CD-ROM or DVD (file:/home/shark/Téléchargements/mageia_boot-nonfree.iso))
[1] > 1

Preparing to start the installation...

Installing...

Failed to display the VM's console because DISPLAY is not set.  Please connect a VNC viewer to localhost:5900.
```

But I don't know how to run a VNC viewer (with `virt-viewer` ?)

### with qemu

With `qemu-kvm` it seems there is a problem of network + problem of permissions + problem of display

```
 % qemu-kvm -name "mageia 5" -M pc-0.12 -m 1024 \ VM/VirtualMachines linux-7o7a
-boot d \
-drive file=/run/media/shark/VM/VirtualMachines/mageia.qcow2,if=virtio,index=0,media=disk,format=qcow2 \
-drive file=/home/shark/Téléchargements/mageia_boot-nonfree.iso,index=1,media=cdrom \
-net nic,model=virtio,macaddr=52:54:00:05:11:11 \
-balloon virtio \
-vga cirrus
Warning: vlan 0 is not connected to host network
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(qemu-system-x86_64:7189): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

### with virt-manager

libvirt URI : `qemu:///system`

When I want to finish installation :

```
Impossible de terminer l'installation : « internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2016-01-16T15:47:09.003883Z qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev pty,id=charserial0: Failed to create chardev
 »

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1969, in do_install
    guest.start_install(meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 442, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 506, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 3585, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2016-01-16T15:47:09.003883Z qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev pty,id=charserial0: Failed to create chardev
```

What is chardev ? *Connecting to monitor* : a problem of display ?

## KVM configuration

I wil ltry to say here all needed informations :

I'm running **openSUSE Leap 42.1** *64 bits*

My proc is an **Intel i7 3610QM 2.3Ghz** so it allow virtualisation.
That's confirmed when I run `% egrep '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo`, I get `vmx`.

SO I ran `modprobe kvm-intel` (Do I need to run it only once or each time I start a session ?).

Do I need to do `modprobe vhost-net` ?

- `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` by default : all commented
- `/etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf` by default : all commented
- `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf` : `unix_sock_group = "libvirt"` + `unix_sock_rw_perms = "0770"` + `auth_unix_rw = "none"`

I added my user and qemu user in libvirt group :

```
usermod -a -G libvirt qemu
usermod -a -G libvirt shark
```

I Changed the configuration in `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf` as above.

And then : `rclibvirtd restart`

And I think I have to configure my VNC access in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` but I don't know how.

## Question

How can I configure my environnement and KVM to run my VMs ? 
As I said :

> No matter for me to use virsh or qemu-kvm, virtlib or qemu, CLI or
>   GUI, I just want my VMs to run

PS : It is the first time I tried virtualization on linux, be indulgent. I'm new in the StackEchange Community so maybe I made mistake by redacting this question, be indulgent. I'm french so I'm not so fluent in English, be indulgent. So please BE **indulgent** :)

---

**Update (21/01/2016) :**
I also try to install a VM with the GUI of vm-install in virt-manager and install it in the default storage pool `/var/lib/libvirt/images/default`

```
Impossible de terminer l'installation : « missing target information for device /var/lib/libvirt/images/default/generic.qcow2 »

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1969, in do_install
    guest.start_install(meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 442, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 506, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 3585, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: missing target information for device /var/lib/libvirt/images/default/generic.qcow2
```

**Update (10/02/2016) :**
It's seems I regressed, now I just can't connect to QEMU/KVM (qemu:///system) with virt-manager, I get an error message :

```
Impossible de se connecter à libvirt.
internal error: Cannot find suitable emulator for x86_64
```

And it seem's my QEMU is too new :

```
systemctl status libvirtd
libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since mer. 2016-02-10 18:37:24 CET; 52min ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           http://libvirt.org
 Main PID: 1940 (libvirtd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
           └─1940 /usr/sbin/libvirtd --listen

févr. 10 19:23:52 linux-7o7a.site libvirtd[1940]: unsupported configuration: QEMU 2.3.1 is too new for help parsing
févr. 10 19:23:52 linux-7o7a.site libvirtd[1940]: Failed to probe capabilities for /usr/bin/qemu-system-i386: unsupported configuration: QEMU 2.3.1 is too new for help parsing
févr. 10 19:23:53 linux-7o7a.site libvirtd[1940]: unsupported configuration: QEMU 2.3.1 is too new for help parsing
févr. 10 19:23:53 linux-7o7a.site libvirtd[1940]: Failed to probe capabilities for /usr/bin/qemu-kvm: unsupported configuration: QEMU 2.3.1 is too new for help parsing
févr. 10 19:23:53 linux-7o7a.site libvirtd[1940]: unsupported configuration: QEMU 2.3.1 is too new for help parsing
févr. 10 19:23:53 linux-7o7a.site libvirtd[1940]: Failed to probe capabilities for /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: unsupported configuration: QEMU 2.3.1 is too new for help parsing
févr. 10 19:23:53 linux-7o7a.site libvirtd[1940]: unsupported configuration: QEMU 2.3.1 is too new for help parsing
févr. 10 19:23:53 linux-7o7a.site libvirtd[1940]: Failed to probe capabilities for /usr/bin/qemu-kvm: unsupported configuration: QEMU 2.3.1 is too new for help parsing
févr. 10 19:23:53 linux-7o7a.site libvirtd[1940]: invalid argument: could not find capabilities for arch=x86_64 domaintype=qemu 
févr. 10 19:23:53 linux-7o7a.site libvirtd[1940]: internal error: Cannot find suitable emulator for x86_64
```

And :

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64
Warning: default mac address being used, creating potential for address conflict
Unable to init server: Impossible de se connecter : Connexion refusée

(qemu-system-x86_64:5610): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Answer (score 1):

for me it was a corrupt installation of brlapi.

To debug it I killed libvirt, the backend for Virtual Machine Manager and Gnome Boxes with

```
sudo systemctl stop libvirtd
```

and then ran it in the terminal with

```
sudo libvirtd
```

The first error hinted that

```
internal error: Child process (LC_ALL=C PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin HOME=/root USER=Douglas LOGNAME=adams /bin/qemu-system-alpha -help) unexpected exit status 127: /bin/qemu-system-alpha: error while loading shared libraries: libbrlapi.so.0.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then to find what provides libbrlapi, I ran

```
$ dnf provides --refresh "libbrlapi.so*"
brlapi-0.6.3-10.fc23.x86_64 : Application Programming Interface for BRLTTY
```

Afterwhich, a quick reinstall fixed my issue

```
sudo dnf reinstall brlapi
```

This was likely caused by some core tinkering I had done to compile brillo, php and app engine.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer the QEMU problems.

1) `-net nic` requires something like `-net user` for functional networking.

2) As `vm-install` hints, your `$DISPLAY` variable isn't set correctly. You need to either configure this or disable QEMU's output with `-display none`.

3) Please don't use `cirrus`; use `std` or `qxl` instead: https://www.kraxel.org/blog/2014/10/qemu-using-cirrus-considered-harmful/

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer but unfortunately I'm not using the computer and this OS anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Some people may want to enable virtualisation in CPU options in "BIOS".

Comment: Of course virtualization was enabled in BIOS.

Comment: I was not as clever as you were...